# How can I include an Apple Help Book when building my app for OSX

Tags: macos, firemonkey

I have developed a Firemonkey app for Windows and OSX. I have also developed an Apple Help Book containing the help for my application when it is run on OSX. (I have a different help system when running in Windows.) Apple's recommended location for the help bundle is in the app's Contents/Resources folder. I can copy the help bundle there manually but it gets deleted every time I run my app in the IDE or deploy my app.

I thought about trying to use the deployment manager but this only allows files to be deployed, not bundles. The help bundle contains a large number of files spread amongst various folders and it would be tedious to set each file up individually in the deployment manager. Moreover, I would have to change the setup every time I added or deleted a page from help since each page is a separate HTML file in the bundle.

So for now, I am manually pasting the help bundle into Contents/Resources. Does anyone know of a more efficient method to incorporate the help bundle?

Comment: You are not alone... When I make a release build for macOS I always run a `Shell Script` afterwards to perform the specific tasks that I cannot configure Delphi to do. I am curious to see if something comes up here that can automate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I came to the conclusion that the only reasonable way to incorporate an Apple helpbook is to paste its bundle into the app bundle at the location Contents/Resources. I thought about locating it elsewhere but Contents/Resources is where Apple recommends it should go. This is inconvenient because it gets erased whenever I redeploy the app or run it from the IDE. But until Firemonkey is enhanced to make provision for helpbooks, this seems to be the only acceptable way to do it. The program 'Packages' http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html is then a great way to package the app for issue to customers.